# Color slow websites down?

Tags: html

Is there any reason I should avoid using colors instead of grayscale in order to perform great speed performance of a website?

To make this question relevant:

Will this ever be loaded and displayed faster

```
<form style="background-color: #7c7c7c">...</form>
```

than this?

```
<form style="background-color: #0000ff">...</form>
```

Comment: No, why should it be? And even if it _would_ be faster, do you really care if it's faster by 0.000000000001 second?

Comment: Well ok, it's faster to use only one of RGB, because then only one LED out of all 3 will be lit, so it will be faster, and will use less electricity, but your clients will never see this performance

Comment: Not really though. First, the panel type would determine if any fewer nodes had to be lit. Next, the difference in time to light a given point is so negligible that is could never be in the right order of magnitude close to the refresh rate. Last, there is no reason to assume a driver board lights colors in series.

Comment: If you're using one LED out of three then you'd be getting various brightnesses or red, green, or blue … not grey which needs a mix of the three.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

While it is possible to design systems which don't deal with colour information for a performance gain, web browsers **do** deal with colour information (and so much other information that any gains from not dealing in colour would be negligible).